# Eclipse how not to debug jar files

Tags: java, eclipse

When I am debugging my code, the execution is trying to go inside the jar file classes and asking for source path. Why is it going there? How can I prevent it going inside the jar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `F6` to `step-over` during debugging on the external calls , this will avoid getting into the jar file.

Comment: That is the ironical part - it is not skipping and still looking for source.

Comment: I have just tested it on my eclipse , it works fine as expected. maybe you have plugin conflict. Try fresh eclipse .